# LiveCD asking for password

Tags: password

I’m running the LiveCD of Kubuntu (latest release). However, to login, it is asking for a password.

Where I can get this information for LiveCD credenials?

Answer (score 0):

There is no password, something must of gone wrong while burning it to a disk.

Re download  [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/) and burn it again.

Or you might want to try the live USB instead of a DVD. Live USB Installation Guide is found [Here](https://userbase.kde.org/Kubuntu/Installation)